# Session manager for logged in users

Tags: c, security, session

I wrote this code to handle logged in users. The session IDs will be stored in cookies. I would like to know if it's usable or if there are security problems.

It uses a 64bit id and another 64bit validation ID. Perhaps this is a bad idea, but here's what I thought: if someone tries to carry a brute force attack and happens to find the first value, he will most likely not have found the second value, so I can destroy that session before it's compromised. Would using a single huge id be better? What size would be considered safe?

I know the ideal would be to write a custom tree to avoid calling `bt_find()` and `bt_remove()` in some places and I plan to do that next.

**session.h**

```
#ifndef SESSION_H
#define SESSION_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ID_SIZE 8

typedef struct Session_Manager Session_Manager;
typedef struct {
    char id0[ID_SIZE];
    char id1[ID_SIZE];
} Session;

//Every manager has its own set of sessions
Session_Manager *session_manager_new(void);
void session_manager_delete(Session_Manager *sm);

//Expiry is how long it takes for a session to be deleted
void session_manager_set_expiry(Session_Manager *sm, time_t seconds);
time_t session_manager_get_expiry(Session_Manager *sm);

//It's possible to execute a custom function to clean up user_data
void session_manager_set_on_delete(Session_Manager *sm, void (*delete_cb)(void *));
void (*session_manager_get_on_delete(Session_Manager *sm))(void *);

//Delete all expired sessions
void sess_clean_old_sessions(Session_Manager *sm);

//Create new session and associate user_data to it
Session *sess_new_session(Session_Manager *sm, void *user_data);

//Validate session, increase expiry time and return user_data
void *sess_get_data(Session_Manager *sm, Session *session);

//Delete session
void sess_delete_session(Session_Manager *sm, Session *session);

#endif
```

**session.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "session.h"
#include "binary_tree.h"

#define EXPIRY_DEFAULT 3600
#define allocate malloc
#define deallocate free

char *table = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ0123456789";

struct Session_Manager {
    Binary_Tree sessions;
    time_t expiry;
    void (*on_delete)(void *);
};

/* If id0 is correct but id1 is wrong it will fail and the session will be
deleted in order to make bruteforce unlikely to work. id1 is completely ignored
until a session with id0 is found */
typedef struct {
    uint64_t id0;
    uint64_t id1;
    time_t expiry;
    void *user_data;
} _Session;

//Callback to compare two sessions
static int compare_sessions(const void *s0_ptr, const void *s1_ptr)
{
    const _Session *s0 = s0_ptr;
    const _Session *s1 = s1_ptr;

    return s0->id0 - s1->id0;
}

//Callback to clean old sessions
static void clean_sessions(void *s_ptr, void *sm_ptr)
{
    _Session *s = s_ptr;
    Session_Manager *sm = sm_ptr;

    if(s->expiry <= time(NULL)){
        if(sm->on_delete != NULL)
            sm->on_delete(s->user_data);

        bt_remove(&sm->sessions, s);
        deallocate(s);
    }
}

static void delete_all_content(void *s_ptr, void *sm_ptr)
{
    _Session *s = s_ptr;
    Session_Manager *sm = sm_ptr;

    if(sm->on_delete != NULL)
        sm->on_delete(s->user_data);

    deallocate(s);
}

//Every manager has its own set of sessions
Session_Manager *session_manager_new(void)
{
    Session_Manager *sm = allocate(sizeof(Session_Manager));
    if(sm == NULL)
        return NULL;

    bt_init(&sm->sessions, compare_sessions);
    sm->expiry = EXPIRY_DEFAULT;
    sm->on_delete = NULL;

    return sm;
}

void session_manager_delete(Session_Manager *sm)
{
    bt_iterate_arg(&sm->sessions, delete_all_content, sm);      
    bt_free(&sm->sessions);
    deallocate(sm);
}

//Expiry is how long it takes for a session to be deleted
void session_manager_set_expiry(Session_Manager *sm, time_t seconds)
{
    sm->expiry = seconds;
}

time_t session_manager_get_expiry(Session_Manager *sm)
{
    return sm->expiry;
}

void session_manager_set_on_delete(Session_Manager *sm, void (*delete_cb)(void *))
{
    sm->on_delete = delete_cb;
}

void (*session_manager_get_on_delete(Session_Manager *sm))(void *)
{
    return sm->on_delete;
}

//Delete all expired sessions
void sess_clean_old_sessions(Session_Manager *sm)
{
    bt_iterate_arg(&sm->sessions, clean_sessions, sm);
}

//Create new session
Session *sess_new_session(Session_Manager *sm, void *user_data)
{
    int file_descriptor, ret;
    _Session *new_session = allocate(sizeof(_Session));
    unsigned int random;
    unsigned char *ids = (unsigned char *)new_session;

    if(new_session == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if((file_descriptor = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)) == -1){
        deallocate(new_session);
        return NULL;
    }

    generate_random:
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ID_SIZE * 2; ++i){
        if(read(file_descriptor, &random, sizeof(int)) == -1){
            deallocate(new_session);
            close(file_descriptor);
            return NULL;
        }

        random = random % 62;
        ids[i] = table[random];     
    }

    if((ret = bt_insert(&sm->sessions, new_session)) != BT_SUCCESS){
        if(ret == BT_DUPLICATE)
            goto generate_random;

        deallocate(new_session);
        close(file_descriptor);
        return NULL;
    }

    close(file_descriptor);
    new_session->expiry = time(NULL) + sm->expiry;
    new_session->user_data = user_data;

    return (Session *) new_session;
}

//Validate session, increase expiry time and return user_data
void *sess_get_data(Session_Manager *sm, Session *session)
{
    _Session *real_session = bt_find(&sm->sessions, session);
    if(real_session == NULL)
        return NULL;

    //Check id1
    if(real_session->id1 != *(uint64_t *)session->id1){
        if(sm->on_delete != NULL)
            sm->on_delete(real_session->user_data);

        bt_remove(&sm->sessions, real_session);
        deallocate(real_session);
        return NULL;
    }

    real_session->expiry = time(NULL) + sm->expiry;
    return real_session->user_data;
}

//Delete session
void sess_delete_session(Session_Manager *sm, Session *session)
{
    _Session *real_session = bt_find(&sm->sessions, session);

    //There's no session with this id
    if(real_session == NULL)
        return;

    if(sm->on_delete != NULL)
        sm->on_delete(real_session->user_data);

    bt_remove(&sm->sessions, real_session);
    deallocate(real_session);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am going to be very urandom here.

1. `ids[i] = table[random]` badly decreases the entropy. Instead of 64 random bits, your ID has less than 48.
2. Can you elaborate on a use case, especially how the validation ID is used.
3. As much as I am against global variables here is one exception I am ready to accept: `/dev/urandom` can well be opened once when the process starts. There's no real difference between a global file descriptor and a global literal. Besides, its randomness doesn't degrade.
4. sess_new_session is overcomplicated. Factor out getting random number; reuse same `new_session` in case of `BT_DUPLICATE`. See also note 2.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm using that table because I need to set cookies with the id and just copying the random bytes directly produces invalid characters. The id1 is used in `sess_get_data()`, if id1 does not match, it will destroy the session. I don't understand how to reuse same `new_session` since the id is already associated with another session? What length would you consider safe?